# Auto print option in xhtml2pdf python library

Tags: python, django, printing

```
  def pdf_invoice(request, id=None):
     # some code

     return render_to_pdf(
        'voucher_pdf/voucher_pdf.html',
        {
            'pagesize': page_size,
            'title': title,
            'init_data': init_data,

        }
    )

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()

    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

The pdf print options get populated when I call the pdf_invoice function through url. but I need auto print dialog option.. Is there any solution. If the question is unclear do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something, maybe you can do this "**request.get_full_path()**" for pdf_invoice's url.